# List of correct terms for inhabitants of countries

Tags: terminology

The term for inhabitants of countries often can't be deduced by the countries name:

For example:

> Saarland - Saarländer

*but:*

> Deutschland - Deutscher (not Deutschländer)
>
> Russland - Russe (not Russländer)

Also there are more obscure forms:

> Monaco - Monegasse
>
> Elfenbeinküste - Ivorer

Is there a list of correct terms for inhabitants of countries?

Comment: [...]dass der amtliche Staatenname im Deutschen mittlerweile Cote dIvoire lautet. [...] Die einzig korrekte Einwohnerbezeichnung lautet dementsprechend dann Ivorer/Ivorerin. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/einwohnerbezeichnungen-zu-togo-elfenbeinkueste-etc)

Comment: How about this: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnonym

Comment: @elena Interesting link. However, some might wonder why an Este isn't called Estländer while an Engländer isn't called Enge. I guess there's no rule at all. Thus we have to learn all them by heart and a complete list might be helpful.

Comment: Little fun fact: In Namibia the 'Deutschländer' is the expression for Germans from Germany (in opposition to a Namibian with German origin) . See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Sprache_in_Namibia#Einige_typisch_namibisch-deutsche_W%C3%B6rter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can download the list in the web links section of this wiki page:

[Liste der Staaten der Erde](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Staaten_der_Erde)

The link is "Verzeichnis der Staatennamen für den amtlichen Gebrauch...", a pdf document from the [Department for Foreign Affairs of Germany](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Laenderinformationen/Linkbox-Staatennamen.html). You will find the terms for the inhabitants in the fourth column ("Bezeichnung der Staatsangehörigen").

Comment: Great! Now that I know where to look for, I also found a [PDF list from the Austrian Department on Foreign Affairs](http://www.bmeia.gv.at/aussenministerium/aussenpolitik/voelkerrecht/staatenliste-pdf.html), which includes an Index and German AND English Terms.